# Error in my python code to create a counter to compare two lists and score their likeness

Tags: python

I have tried creating code which will count the number of items in a list which are in the same order as they are in another list, and add one to the count. The countPerformer should then add an additional one to the count for each subsequent place out of place each of the out of place items are.

Here is my attempted code:

```
def countPerformer(col1, col2):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(col1)):
        if col1[i] == col2[i]:
            count += 1
        else:
            for j in range(i, 20):
                if col1[i] == col2[j]:
                    count += (j - i)
                    break
    return count


col1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
col2 = [2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
print(countPerformer(col1, col2)) # Output should be 26 but returns 18
```

It should return 26 i believe however it returns 18 when i run it. (each number which is in the correct place means that a 1 is added to the count, where as in the example, as the two is one place different between the two list it should add a two to the count).

Comment: The function is named `countPerformer()`, but then you're trying to call `count_same_order()`.  This code will not even run.  Please post the real code.

Comment: @JohnGordon Hi sorry about that, i have updated it so that it should be right

Comment: If the position is ten different is count incremented by 10?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are using the absolute differences between `j` and `i`, but you also need to accommodate for the additional 1 for that position.

The following code should produce the correct output:

#### Code:

```
def countPerformer(col1, col2):
    counter = 0
    for i, col1_val in enumerate(col1):
        if col1_val == col2[i]:
            counter += 1
        else:
            for j, col2_val in enumerate(col2):
                if col1_val == col2_val:
                    counter += abs(j-i) + 1
    return counter

col1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
col2 = [2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

print(countPerformer(col1, col2))
```

#### Output:

```
26
```